# Screw Drive garage door opener motor won't open but motor runs for 1-2 seconds

Tags: garage, garage-door-opener, garage-door

My garage door motor which opens and closes on a screw drive system has stopped opening my door. When I press the remote or button in the garage it attempts to open for just a second or 2 than quits. What is my issue? Do I need a new motor or can it be fixed....

So I recent had a Garage door "professional" come out to my house and look at my garage. I originally thought I was having a motor problem because it would only lift the door sporadically. After performing a 25 point inspection he believed he located the problem, which was the spring system from my Wayne Dalton garage door (torquemaster). He told me how horrible of a system they are and they don't fix them; because of that, they only replace the entire system and that would cost me $700 or more. So now I'm left trying to figure out what I need: torquemaster springs, bracket assembly, both, or if I need something completely different. I need some Wayne Dalton experience.

Comment: Maybe the mechanism needs cleaning and lubricating?

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Stack Exchange. Is the motor stalled, or is it turning? If it's turning, what else is moving?

Comment: The model of the opener would be helpful if it is a belt driven model the belt may have jumped or broken. We are all guessing without the model number.

Comment: It's a genie Pro Screw Drive

Comment: When I hit the button in the garage I can hear the motor for a second attempt to open then stops. I have also lubricated the everything not even 2 weeks ago

Comment: Pull the latch that disconnects the opener from the door, and test them separately. Open and close the door manually - does it bind or stick? Then operate the power opener - does it turn the screw and move the latch?

Comment: I have pulled the latch and open the door manually it does not stick comma and then motor operates when the garage is not attached

Comment: If the door opens smoothly and the screw turns smoothly but when you put them together it doesn't work, then it's possible the screw threads are damaged.

Comment: If threads are damaged do I need to place entire Unit? This issue is a little weird cuz I had same problem 2 weeks ago for like 24 hours then all of a sudden it started working again with no issues.

Comment: I haven't worked on many screw drive door openers but many machines that use acme thread that I believe is the type of thread on the drive. When it works fine without a load but not with a load there are 2 options that I know of 1st if the nut has a nylon, delron liner that may be worn out and needs to be replaced, 2nd screws need lubrication cleaning the screw and then using a teflon spray works well in a dusty area compared to grease that will attract dust and need to be cleaned more often.

Comment: Ed is right, you can replace the threaded insert that engages the lead screw.